# Remove sudoers using script

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, sudo

At the moment I'm working on a solution to prevent all admins users (except one particular) from running `sudo`. I can add a specific user to sudoers by running:

```
sudo -i
echo '$username  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

Then I'd like to remove `%admin     ALL = (ALL) ALL` within sudoers file which would just leave the above admin as the only sudo admin. However I cannot seem to find a way on how to remove/replace a particular string within sudoers.

I'd like to make this into a script hence using visudo and manually adjusting won't work for me. If there a way to run visudo from script and adjust a particular line within sudoers that would be ideal, but I couldn't find anything when researching on the Web.

I've seen a solution here:

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/brian/entry/edit_sudoers_file_from_a_script4?lang=en

which works in Linux. Is it possible to make it work in macOS?

Comment: At first glance the solution on the linked page should also work in macOS. Can you add some details on where/how exactly it fails? Also, as this is basically a "how do I delete a specific line from a text file with a script" type of question, what other kind of research have you already done

Comment: PS: I won't go on to list the various ways how any admin user not part of `sudoers` can easily get their `sudo` rights back...

Comment: PPS: But you may want to use double quotes instead of single quotes in your `echo` statement above :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternate method. Lines are not added or deleted from the sudoers file. The line giving admin root rights is commented out and we create a separate file with mac_admin's rights in the directory /etc/sudoers.d. And as a bonus, the original sudoers file is backed up.

```
printf '%s\n' 'mac_admin  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' > /tmp/99-macadmin

visudo -c -f /tmp/99-macadmin &&
install -o 0 -g 0 -m 440 /tmp/99-macadmin /etc/sudoers.d

sed $'s/%admin\t/# %admin/' /etc/sudoers > /tmp/sudoers

visudo -c -f /tmp/sudoers &&
install -B .orig -b -o 0 -g 0 -m 440 /tmp/sudoers /etc/sudoers

rm /tmp/sudoers /tmp/99-macadmin
```

Comment: Impressive! I was not aware that's an option as my bash skills are incredibly lacking. I'll test this and let you know if it works - very interested to implement this solution as it sounds much safer than editing the actual sudoers like you said. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: That worked as you described - I was just thinking however, what would a script look like to reverse this change. Would it include renaming the edited script to .orig and .orig to default? Apologies as I am just doing my best learning bash, however there might be a time when there might be a need to revert to original without doing a file any direct intervention and using Jamf Pro policy instead. 
I would imagine a policy for applying this change with the script you have so kindly written and a reversal policy which would could be scoped to appropriate machines and undo changes.

Comment: I've just realised I can just delete the edited script and rename the .orig back to default instead, sorry! That was silly of me.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, you can use

```
printf '/^%%admin ALL = (ALL) ALL$/d\nw\nq\n' | ed -s sudoers
```

or, if you want to catch the line independent of the number of space characters, tabs etc used

```
printf '/^%%admin[[:blank:]]*ALL[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*(ALL)[[:blank:]]*ALL$/d\nw\nq\n' | ed sudoers
```

in `bash` to remove the admin line (the double `%%` are required to prevent `printf` from interpreting them as formatting instructions).

The usual caveats about editing `sudoers` without relying on the syntax checks done by `visudo` apply. So it might be safer to run the following, or at least have another root shell running so you can fix any issues without getting locked out)

```
cp /etc/sudoers /tmp
chmod +w /tmp/sudoers
printf '/^%%admin[[:blank:]]*ALL[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*(ALL)[[:blank:]]*ALL$/d\nw\nq\n' \
    | ed /tmp/sudoers
if visudo -c -f /tmp/sudoers; then
    echo "All well"
    mv -f /tmp/sudoers /etc/sudoers
    chmod -w /etc/sudoers
else
    echo "Uups, something went wrong"
fi
```

(Script untested, because I don't want to mess with my `sudoers` file)

Comment: I've tested the above script and it may indeed work with some adjustment as the echo returns "All well" however, I believe it isn't removing that particular line still as I've checked sudoers file and %admin is still present. The return code is `Running script Test - edit sudoers...
Script exit code: 0
Script result: 2111
?
/tmp/sudoers: parsed OK
All well`

Comment: @merkeesox Please add your sudoers file to the question then, so it‘s easier to verify what is going wrong.

Comment: @merkeesox Try again. BUT: currently no additional users besides `root` are enabled for sudo, so make sure you don’t lock yourself out!

Comment: That's okay, I've got the root account enabled and when I log in I can edit it back to its original values without affecting ownership and permissions of sudoers file. 

I'll try that now.

Answer (score 1):

Amazing! It worked! Thank you very much! @nohillside

I'll add a line above that to add a user mac_admin before the script executes so the final version should look like this.

```
echo 'mac_admin  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

cp /etc/sudoers /tmp
chmod +w /tmp/sudoers
printf '/^%%admin.*ALL = (ALL) ALL$/d\nw\nq\n' | ed /tmp/sudoers
if visudo -c -f /tmp/sudoers; then
    echo "All well"
    mv -f /tmp/sudoers /etc/sudoers
    chmod -w /etc/sudoers
else
    echo "Uups, something went wrong"
fi
```

Just FYI I am running this script by scoping it to my machine on Jamf Pro so it excecutes via a recurring check-in policy.